# Як назвати переклад сайту на українську чи російську мову?

Tags: вживання-слів

Треба скласти завдання на переклад англомовного сайту на російську й українську мови. Чи правильно буде сказати русифікация сайту? Такий вираз стосовно програм, прошивок і т.п. є [вживаним](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&rlz=1C1VFKB_en__709__709&oq=%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.41418j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), аде Тлумачний словник в 11т. надає лише по одному значенню цих слів:

> УКРАЇНІЗА́ЦІЯ, ї, жін. Впровадження української культури, мови,
>   звичаїв. ЦК КП(б)У і Раднарком України твердо і послідовно проводили
>   [у 1920—1925 рр.] українізацію школи (Історія УРСР, II, 1957, 282);
>   Вже йшла мова про українізацію установ, і Сашенька виявила охоту
>   знайомитись з українською мовою (Володимир Гжицький, Вел. надії, 1963,
>   27).
>
> РУСИФІКА́ЦІЯ, ї, жін. У царській Росії — насильницьке запровадження
>   російської мови, культури і т. ін. серед національних меншостей. До
>   революції на Україні не було державних шкіл з українською мовою
>   навчання. Як і в ряді інонаціональних околиць, царизм тут насильно
>   проводив русифікацію (Народна творчість та етнографія, 2, 1967, 8).

Отже, як правильно сказати?

Answer (score 7):

Правильно буде сказати [**ЛОКАЛІЗАЦІЯ**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83).

Також можна казати **українізація** або **русифікація**, але при цьому не уникнути двозначності під час спілкування з тими, хто не в темі програмної адаптації.

> В обчислювальній техніці **українізація** — це локалізація комп'ютерів
>   та програмного забезпечення, тобто переклад інтерфейсу користувача на
>   роботу з українською абеткою та українською мовою.

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)